# SVG image file not showing full image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a svg image file that does not show full image when i call it from external page. It only shows about half the image. Does anyone know why?

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>


<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>

<body>

<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="image.svg#Layer_1" /></svg>


<script>

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**IMAGE.SVG**

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="433px" height="433px" viewBox="0 0 433 433" enable-background="new 0  0 433 433" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#00AEEF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="7" stroke- miterlimit="10" cx="216.5" cy="216.5" r="213"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify width and height on the root svg element, it will default to arbitrary dimensions of "100%", so try explicitly setting the dimensions in INDEX.HTML like this:

`<svg class="icon" width="433px" height="433px"><use xlink:href="image.svg#Layer_1" /></svg>`